# Minitoc in Supplement - renewcommand causes problems?

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

I cannot get the `minitoc` package to create a mini table-of-contents for my Supplementary Material section.

Note that I `renewcommand` a few things so that my Supplementary Material sections, tables, & figures have an `S` in front of them (`S` denotes `Supplement`).

The `minitoc` commands work fine for other sections (before the Supplementary Material section).  But when I place them after `\section{Supplementary Material}`, it doesn't do anything (no table-of-contents is created).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
...
\usepackage{minitoc}
\setcounter{secttocdepth}{5}
...
% when called, the following will include an "S" in
% the numbering system to denote "Supplement".
\newcommand{\beginsupplement}{%
        \renewcommand{\thetable}{S\arabic{table}}%
        \renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}%
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{S\arabic{section}}%
    \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{S\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}%   
    }
...
...
\begin{document}

\dominitoc
\dosecttoc
\dosectlof
\dosectlot

\tableofcontents   % works great.  Includes supplement in toc, as it should.
...
...
...
\newpage
\beginsupplement    % renews a few commands (see above)

\section{Supplementary Material}

\secttoc  % does nothing
\sectlof  % does nothing
\sectlot  % does nothing
```

Clearly the `\renewcommand`s for `\beginsupplement` are causing issues.  But how/why?  And what can I do about it?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Perhaps the easiest way is to make the supplement a separate document with its own toc.  You can use pdfpages to copy the original document (completed pdf) into the new one.

Comment: As to why it doesn't work, I would have to get into the intertices of minitoc.  As a debug hint, examine the contents of the toc, lof and lot files.

Answer (score 2):

Admitted, the manual of `minitoc` isn't a little bit unclear about this, but `\secttoc` will do nothing if there's no `\subsection` etc, because it should provide a section - toc, not a ToC about sections.

The `\sectlof` and `\sectlot` commands require the usage of the `insection` option to `minitoc`, otherwise figures etc. are entered in the global LoF and LoT.

`\dominitoc` does not apply for `article` class since it's designed to operate on a per-chapter base.

The `\renewcommand` does **not** cause problem here!

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
% when called, the following will include an "S" in
% the numbering system to denote "Supplement".

\newcommand{\beginsupplement}{%
  \renewcommand{\thetable}{S\arabic{table}}%
  \renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}%
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{S\arabic{section}}%
  \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{S\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}%   
}


\usepackage[hints,insection]{minitoc}
\mtcsetdepth{secttoc}{2}
\begin{document}
\dosecttoc
\dosectlof
\dosectlot

\tableofcontents   % works great.  Includes supplement in toc, as it should.
\fakelistoftables
\fakelistoffigures
\section{foo}
\subsection{Foo subsection}

\beginsupplement
\section{Supplementary Material}
\secttoc  
\sectlof 
\sectlot 

\subsection{Foo subsection of Supplements}
\subsection{Other subsection of Supplements}

\begin{figure}
\caption{A figure in supplements}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\caption{A table in supplements}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]